# How to express random variable $V(X)$ given function $V(x)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance, expected-value

I have come across a question which reads as follows:
For a random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2 < \infty$, deﬁne the function $V (x) = E((X −x)^2)$ where $'E'$ denotes expectation. Express the random variable V (X) in terms of $\mu, \sigma^2$:

**What I have so far:** I am able to calculate $V(x)=\sigma^2+\mu2-2x\mu+x^2$
. The answer is $V(X)=\sigma^2+\mu2-2X\mu+X^2$.

My question is why we can't substitute $X$ directly into the expression for $V$ to ge $E((X-X)^2)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually have:$$V(x)=\int \left(X (\omega)-x\right)^2P(d\omega)$$

Now if I substitute $x=X(\omega)$ then this $\omega$ becomes a **free** variable on LHS but a  **bound** variable (ranging over $\Omega$) on RHS.

This is not allowed.

---

The situation is up to a certain level comparable with the following:

It is true in $\mathbb R$ that $\forall x\exists y\;[ x<y]$.

Nevertheless something that is not true arises if we substitute $x=y+1$.

This because the free variable $y$ is placed on a spot where it is bound by quantifier $\exists y$.

Comment: I don't really follow this argument, how would this work if the random variables were discrete?

Comment: No difference at all if the rv is discrete. Also in that case you can write the expectation as an integral wrt the probability measure involved.

Comment: What is a **bound variable**? Haven't seen this term in probability books.

Comment: @JamesWhite The distinction between bound and free variables is explicitly handled in logics. Not that you need that on that level so don't worry. Often mathematicians do well without being well informed and purely on intuition. It is definitely not a probability matter. Note that an expression like $y=\int_0^1xdx$ gives us information about variable $y$ but tells us nothing about variable $x$ (actually we can replace by another variable $u$ without affecting the info). That indicates that in the expression $y$ is a free variable and $x$ a bounded variable.

Answer (score 1):

$V(x)=E[(X−x)^2]$ is a function of $x$ and will vary with $x$.  Clearly it is non-negative, and you should be able to show that it is minimised when $x=\mu_X^{\,}$ the expectation (assuming $X$ has a mean) at which point $V(x_\mu)$ is $\sigma_X^2$ the variance of $X$.

So if this variance is positive (i.e. $X$ is not almost surely constant), then $V(x)$ will be at least this much for all $x$.  Indeed you can say $V(x)=\sigma_X^2 + (x-\mu_X^{\,})^2$

This shows that (unless $X$ is almost surely constant) neither $V(x)$ nor $V(X)$ will be zero.

Now that you know what $V(x)$ is as a function of $x$, you can apply it to a random variable.  So it is meaningful to talk about $V(X)$ as function of a random variable, remembering this too would be a random variable.  And indeed you would have  $V(X)=\sigma_X^2 + (X-\mu_X^{\,})^2$

Since $V(X)$ is a random variable, you can find its expected value.  This turns out tto be $E[V(X)]=2\sigma_X^2$.  None of this is affected by whether $X$ is a discrete or continuous random variable, though some of these statements assume $\sigma_X^2$ and $\mu_X^{\,}$ exist.